# Emacs not working in console

Tags: emacs

When I try to start emacs in the console on my Snow Leopard machine I get the following:

`emacs: Cannot open termcap database file`

But if I start screen first, then emacs does start, but I get the following error message:

`Error in init file: error: "Unknown keyword :risky"`

I installed emacs using homebrew.

Answer (score 1):

> The `risky` is a keyword for `defcustom`, which was added in Emacs 23.1 (see [NEWS.23.1](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/NEWS.23.1)). So, either upgrade your Mac's Emacs, download a newer version of custom (may not be possible at this point), or remove the starter kit by commenting out `(require 'package)` in your `.init.el`.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386170/what-is-the-risky-in-emacs/5386504#5386504